# Finding python site-packages directory with CMake

Tags: python, cmake

I use CMake to build my application. How can I find where the python site-packages directory is located?  I need the path in order to compile an extension to python.

CMake has to be able to find the path on all three major OS as I plan to deploy my application on Linux, Mac and Windows.

I tried using

```
include(FindPythonLibs)
find_path( PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES site-packages ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}/.. )
```

however that does not work.

I can also obtain the path by running

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

on the shell, but how would I invoke that from CMake ?

SOLUTION:

Thanks, Alex.
So the command that gives me the site-package dir is:

```
execute_process ( COMMAND python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

The OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE command is needed to remove the trailing new line.

Comment: Just for future reference; I found this great package: https://github.com/lyricat/Hotot/tree/master/cmake/modules

Comment: For those using python 3.x, the `print` statement should read: `print(get_python_lib())`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute external processes in cmake with [execute_process](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:execute_process) (and get the output into a variable if needed, as it would be here).

Comment: This looks like a hack.  Is this still (after six years) the way to go?

Comment: @TorstenBronger Why is this a hack? CMake needs to get the info from somewhere, so why not ask who knows best i.e. Python directly?

Comment: FWIW, my intention for using CMake is to use it to abstract away such things.

Comment: It probably is a hack, but now it's been [hacked into CMake officially](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPython.html#result-variables): "Python_SITELIB / Third-party platform independent installation directory. / Information returned by `distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=False,standard_lib=False)`."

Answer (score 11):

Slightly updated version that I used for [lcm](https://github.com/lcm-proj-lcm):

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -c "if True:
    from distutils import sysconfig as sc
    print(sc.get_python_lib(prefix='', plat_specific=True))"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SITE
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

This sets `PYTHON_SITE` to the appropriate prefix-relative path, suitable for use like:

```
install(
  FILES ${mypackage_python_files}
  DESTINATION ${PYTHON_SITE}/mypackage)
```

(Please don't install to an absolute path! Doing so bypasses `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.)

Comment: What's the point of the `if True:`? Only to allow you to indent the remaining 2 lines?

Comment: Exactly that: so that the inline script does not break into the indentation of the surrounding CMake code.

Answer (score 8):

Since CMake 3.12 you can use [FindPython](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) module which populates `Python_SITELIB` and `Python_SITEARCH` variables for architecture independent and specific libraries, respectively.

Example:

```
find_package(Python ${PYTHON_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
Python_add_library(foo MODULE
    src/foo.cc src/python_interface.cc
)
install(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ${Python_SITEARCH}/foo)
```

Comment: The problem is, it appears that `Python_SITEARCH` / `Python_SITELIB` / etc. are absolute paths, which (as @Matthew notes above) makes them unusable for `install()` because it will break `CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH` handling.

Comment: @FeRD It will only half-break, the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH` is still respected, but the whole "absolute" path will be appended to it, e. g. `/builds/python-foo/debian/python3-foo/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/foo/foo.so`
The ideal solution would be not to use CMake for installing at all, however this solution works fine for Debian packaging.

Comment: Have you actually tested that? My experience is, it's incorrect. And I quote from [the CMake documentation for `install`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/install.html): "If a full path (with a leading slash or drive letter) is given it is used directly. If a relative path is given it is interpreted relative to the value of the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable." The path you quoted is an example of a builddir path, which is different from an _install_ path. (The trick of calling `get_python_lib(prefix='')`, as Matthew does above, _does_ work... but CMake doesn't do that.)

Comment: @FeRD I have, altough only as a part of a process of building a Debian package. The path from my previous comment is taken from the output of `make install` command which is run by the debhelper machinery.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible `debhelper` uses `DESTDIR`, instead of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`? `DESTDIR` (as a `make` argument, e.g. `make install DESTDIR=/some/install/path`) **will** prefix even absolute paths.

Comment: @FeRD I am not sure, it looks like it uses `cmake` directly. Here is the anonymised build log, if you can find something in it: https://pastebin.com/TazFVxMZ

Comment: Yep, there it is, line 168: "`dh_auto_install --buildsystem=cmake --builddirectory="/builds/python_foo/.pybuild/pythonX.Y_2.7/build" --destdir="/builds/python_foo/debian/python-foo"`" The CMake setup never actually uses `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` at all, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `get_python_lib(True)` if you are making this extension as a dynamic library. This first parameter should be true if you need the platform specific location (in 64bit linux machines, this could be `/usr/lib64` instead of `/usr/lib`)