# How can I force CMake to look for a library in a specific directory?

Tags: python, linux, cmake

Trying to install a Spenvis package and here's the error I'm getting when running the script:

```
-- Boost version: 1.41.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: Desktop/build
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0', needed by `source/libSpenvis.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's looking for libpython2.6.so.1.0 in /usr/local/lib64, but the library itself is in /usr/lib64.

I'm not a super user, so I can't change/copy the library into the directory nor can I make a link to it. For reference, here's the python script I'm running followed by the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
"""
Main launch script
"""
import os
import sys
import shutil
from subprocess import call

"""
Define path where to find python packages
"""
loc_dir=os.getcwd()
os.chdir("python_utilities")

#Spenvis csv
#############
os.chdir("spenvis_csv")
if not os.path.exists("build"):
    os.mkdir("build")

os.chdir("build")
call("cmake ../", shell=True)
call("make")
os.chdir(loc_dir)
os.chdir("python_utilities")
if not os.path.exists("lib"):
    os.mkdir("lib")

for file_name in os.listdir("spenvis_csv/build/source"):
    if file_name.find("libSpenvis.") !=-1:
        shutil.move("spenvis_csv/build/source/%s" %(file_name),"lib/Spenvis.so") 
os.chdir("..")
```

And the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Make sure the compiler can find include files
include_directories (${PYSPENVIS_SOURCE_DIR})


# get boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
#set(Boost_USE_MULTIEADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
                python
             REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# get python
include(FindPythonLibs)

set(PythonLibs_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_library(Spenvis  SHARED pySpenvisCSV.cc SpenvisCSV.cc SpenvisCSVCollection.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Spenvis ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Taking advice, I ran the following command in the directory with CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY='/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0'
```

This churned out:

```
Boost  found.
Found Boost components:
   python
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (found version "2.7.1") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (found suitable version "2.7.1", minimum required is "2.6") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: blahblahblah
```

Going back to run the install.py program now returns:

```
-- Boost version: 1.41.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (found version "2.6.6") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (found suitable version "2.6.6", minimum required is "2.6") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras original/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/spenvis_csv/build
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0', needed by `source/libSpenvis.so'.  Stop.
```

So, the same error is returned, only now it is claiming it's finding python libraries. Strangely, though, the python libraries it is finding don't exist, which is to say, there is no libpython2.6.so.1.0 in /usr/**local**/lib64   but instead it is located in /usr/lib64.

In the CMakeCache.txt, the lines concerning the desired library are as followed:

```
//No help, variable specified on the command line.
PYTHON_LIBRARIES:UNINITIALIZED=/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0

//Path to a library.
PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so

//Dependencies for the target
Spenvis_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=optimized;boost_python-mt-shared;debug;boost_python-mt-shared-debug;general;/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so;

//Details about finding PythonLibs
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_PythonLibs:INTERNAL=[/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so][/usr/local/include/python2.7][v2.7.1(2.6)]
```

Comment: Did yo try including  /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 into TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES?

Comment: It may help to add the "VERBOSE=1" after your make command:  "make VERBOSE=1".  You'll see every option it thinks it's using, i.e., what cmake passed along.

Comment: Damian, how would I add that specific library correctly?

Comment: have you tried adding `/usr` to cmake search path by: `list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr)`?

Comment: Squid: unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `find_package(PythonLibs)` worked at all. It should print a message like `find_package(Boost)` does. Can you try `find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)`? And which CMake version are you using? There were bugs when multiple Phyton versions are installed on your system. See e.g. [0013794: find_package(PythonLibs) finds different version of Python headers and libraries](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13794)

Comment: I tried adding REQUIRED and still come up with the same error. I'll take a look at that link. Also, I'm using cmake version 2.8.12.2. Thanks!

Comment: Here is another one you might find useful: [cmake finds wrong python libs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660001/cmake-finds-wrong-python-libs)

Comment: I looked at the other thread and gave it a try, It's still not working, though we may have seen progress (maybe even in the forward direction!). Posting the new information now.

Comment: The `cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=...` should put the value into the `CMakeCache.txt` of your build direcory. Please crosscheck that its there. If you're testing your install script from scratch you need to put the `-D` also into your install script. Otherwise its time for debugging your CMake script: first test your script with the latest CMake version to see if it's a already fixed CMake bug. Second try your script in an different environment/computer. Third use `cmake --trace ...` which gives painfully long outputs, but you will see what CMake does while searching for Python in detail.

Comment: Added the lines wherein libpython2.6.so.1.0 appears in the CMakeCache.txt file.

Comment: I'll try another machine later this evening or tomorrow morning. I'm doubtful it will make much of a difference as my machine is but a single cog in a large linux workstation.

Comment: It looks like the file `/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so` is actually Python 2.7.
Normally that should be /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.

I suggest you contact the system admin to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The `/usr` need to be insert in front of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, so it will be found first.

```
list(INSERT 0 CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr)
```

Comment: Sorry, I got moved to a different task for awhile, but I'm now back to this one. I added this towards the beginning of my CmakeLists.txt file, but it still produced this error. Should it go elsewhere?