# How to install Python package with CMake

Tags: python, cmake, installation, package

I have a very simple Python 3 package as part of a bigger project (which is mostly non-Python) that I want to install in the Python path with CMake.  Let us assume the following source code directory structure:

```
|
+---> pypackage
|         |
|         +--> __init__.py
|         |
|         \--> pymodule.py
|
much other stuff
```

For example on Ubuntu, I'd like to have pypackage/ end up in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.  Any Python script containing

```
from pypackage import pymodule
```

must work fine after the installation.

"[Finding python site-packages directory with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242904)" suggests to call Python from CMake to find out this path and store it in a CMake variable.  This looks like a hack to me, and the answers there are rather old.  Is there a canonical way to do this (pretty normal thing IMHO) in CMake?

Comment: I think you can just create a `.pth` file with the path to the `pypackage` in it. See the `site` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

Comment: I don't want to clutter up `sys.path`.